# Compare two dates and filter Sql Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, validation, date

In my software I have a **registered date** as well as **expiry date** as shown below:

[image]

And I'm updating them to the database as shown below:

[image]

Now I would like to **filter** all the records from my **database** where who has **completed** the **expirydate** and give some color to them. (or) can I compare the expiry date with today's date.

For Filtering by name I have done this way:

```
 Dim Name As String = "%" + txtName.Text.ToString + "%"
 Me.CustomersBindingSource.Filter = " FirstName LIKE '" & Name & "'"
```

In the similar way can I do something for the expiry date?If So how do I proceed?

Any suggestions are most welcome..

Comment: do you have the query to return the data based on the date filer already written? If so, if should be relatively easy to convert it to VB code...

Comment: That is what I would love to know :)

Comment: are you saying, from the results of the query above, you would now like to filter the data even further based on the date???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use something like this:

```
Me.CustomersBindingSource.Filter = " ExpiryDate > '" & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "'"
```

Comment: Well, you got the idea :) I'm glad to help you.